# flask bokeh server - figure does not render even locally

Tags: python, flask, localhost, bokeh

I can't run bokeh server within flask beind apache so now I'm trying to serve bokeh within flask locally. The figure does not render.
Here is the flask code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

from bokeh.embed import server_document
@app.route("/")
def techblog():
    try:
        tag = server_document(url=r'/bokeh', relative_urls=True)
        return render_template('techblog.html', tag=tag)
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is the bokeh code:

```
from numpy.random import random
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import column, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import Button, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.server.server import Server

def run(doc):

    fig = figure(title='random data', width=400, height=200, tools='pan,box_zoom,reset,save')

    source = ColumnDataSource(data={'x': [], 'y': []})
    fig.line('x', 'y', source=source)

    def click(n=100):
        source.data = {'x': range(n), 'y': random(n)}

    button = Button(label='update', button_type='success')
    button.on_click(click)

    layout = column(widgetbox(button), fig)
    doc.add_root(layout)
    click()

# configure and run bokeh server
kws = {'port': 5000, 'prefix':'/bokeh','allow_websocket_origin': ['127.0.0.1']}
server = Server(run, **kws)
server.start()
# if __name__ == '__main__':
server.io_loop.add_callback(server.show, '/')
server.io_loop.start()
```

Here is my html template:

```
<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There!</h1>

</br>
{{ tag|safe }}
</br>
{{ tag }}
```

I'm running flask app via python. And on a separate command processor I run bokeh app via,

```
bokeh serve --allow-websocket-origin=localhost:5000 filename.py
```

I only get the tag without "safe" as

```
<script src="/bokeh/autoload.js?bokeh-autoload-element=1001&bokeh-app-path=/bokeh" id="1001"></script>
```

And I have this message on flask console. It is a standart 404:

```
"GET /bokeh/autoload.js?bokeh-autoload-element=1000&bokeh-app-path=/bokeh HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

That'a all. No figure or button is rendered. What should I change to see the figure?

Edit: I've specified the port and the prefix in the bokeh code. The outcome has not changed.

Edit 2: I've add the console msj for 404 error on flask console.

Comment: don't you get any error message when you run Flask in console?

Comment: i think you should use full url `http://localhost:5000/bokeh` to access data from other server which runs on different port. Without that you can try to get `/bokeh`  from Flask, not from Bokeh.

Comment: I don't get any error msg on console. There is just 404.

Comment: and localhost:5000 is same as 127.0.0.1:5000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add some details to @bigreddot's answer.

---

Code didn't work for me too. I even found exactly this code in some tutorial and main problem was that it was using `nginx` which was converting `/bokeh` to `http://127.0.0.1/bokeh`. But on local computer without `nginx` I have to change all urls.

**EDIT:** I found tutorial with this code https://rbtechblog.com/blog/deploy_bokeh_app

---

I start changing code and reduce it to create minimal code which works. I made changes similar to changes mentioned by bigreddot.

---

## Bokeh

I put code directly in file without `def` and without `Server`

**filename.py**

```
from numpy.random import random
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import column, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import Button, ColumnDataSource

def click(n=100):
    source.data = {'x': range(n), 'y': random(n)}

fig = figure(title='random data', width=800, height=400, tools='pan,box_zoom,reset,save')

source = ColumnDataSource(data={'x': [], 'y': []}) # place for data
fig.line('x', 'y', source=source)  # draw plot

button = Button(label='update', button_type='success') # create button
button.on_click(click) # assign function to button

layout = column(fig, widgetbox(button)) # create layout
curdoc().add_root(layout) # add all to document

click() # generate random data at start
```

Now I can run it in console

```
 bokeh serve filename.py
```

and I can see it in web browser using url

```
 http://localhost:5006/filename
```

(`bokeh` should display this url in console after start - if you will use different file or options then you may see different url)

At this moment I don't need any other options but later I will need `--allow-websocket-origin` but I will describe it later.

**BTW:** I not use name **bokeh.py** because it can make problem to import original `bokeh`.

---

## Flask

Because I don't use `nginx` which could convert `/bokeh` to `http://localhost:5006/filename` so I have to use full url in `serve_document`

For test I used `render_template_string` instead of `render_template` so I don't have to create `templates/index.html` so it will easier to copy and test code.

I removed `try/except` to get more details if there will be error.

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, render_template_string
from bokeh.embed import server_document

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    tag = server_document(url='http://localhost:5006/filename')
    #return render_template('index.html', tag=tag)
    return render_template_string('''<div>{{ tag|safe }}</div>''', tag=tag)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Now I can run it

```
python app.py
```

and I can open page in web browser using standard url

```
http://localhost:5000/
```

but I will not see plot and `bokeh` will display

```
Refusing websocket connection from Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'; 
use --allow-websocket-origin=127.0.0.1:5000 
or set BOKEH_ALLOW_WS_ORIGIN=127.0.0.1:5000 to permit this; 
currently we allow origins {'localhost:5006'}
```

so I have to restart `bokeh` with this option

```
bokeh serve filename.py --allow-websocket-origin=127.0.0.1:5000
```

(as bigreddot mentioned it has to be `127.0.0.1`, not `localhost`)

And now `flask` should display plot.

**BTW:** if I use template without any HTML tag

```
render_template_string('''{{ tag|safe }}''', tag=tag)
```

then browser may treat all code (`<script ...></scrip>`) as part of `<head></head>` and it will not display it because browser never display elements which are in `<head></head>` even if there are correct images or plots.

---

Comment: Thank you @furas! It is working locally now. Now I'll try to make it work on a server. Wish me luck!

Comment: I just figured that this is served by bokeh not by flask. I add an h1 tag to the output of the flask and it is not shown on 127.0.0.0 i.e. serving is through bokeh not through flask :/

Comment: flask serves on port 5000, bokeh on port 5006, you have to use correct port to get content from flask. OR you have to configure `flask` to use port `80` and then you can get it without port.

Comment: at least on local computer it needs corrent port to get flask as 127.0.0.1. On server it may need totally different configuration - all depend how works server.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things wrong:

- You have not configured a port, so the Bokeh server will use its default port of 5006 (not 5000)
- You have not configured an app path, so the Bokeh server will serve the app from its default location of `/` (not `/bokeh`)

It's also worth mentioning that if you whitelist `localhost` as an allow websocket origin, then it literally must be `localhost` in the URL bar (i.e. not 127.0.0.1, they are not interchangeable in this context)

Lastly, it's a lot of extra work to put the Bokeh app code in a plain python script that calls `Server` manually, etc. You could just put the contents of `run` in a file and call `bokeh serve --port=5000 app.py` and then the app will be available at `localhost:5000/app`

Comment: I've specified both port and prefix. Nothing in the outcome is changed, unfortunately.

Comment: I've combined the contents of bokeh and flask files. Now I'm getting this error when I serve with bokeh: __ERROR:bokeh.server.views.ws:Refusing websocket connection from Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5000';                       use --allow-websocket-origin=127.0.0.1:5000 or set BOKEH_ALLOW_WS_ORIGIN=127.0.0.1:5000 to permit this; currently we allow origins {'127.0.0.1:80'}
WARNING:tornado.access:403 GET /bokeh/ws?bokeh-protocol-version=1.0&bokeh-session-id=USFpLgANrCyBuxTjd9Yx32Uz8j0GjNXp1InFmacFMQn4 (127.0.0.1) 1.03ms__

Comment: @Saba That error message tells you exactly what to do, right? What’s the issue?

Comment: The issue is I don't see any plots. I've tried the saying in the error message. I'm getting a blank page. Either there is someting naive that I'm doing or I don't know why but I'm not getting any plots. BTW I need to do this on separate files, one file does not work for the real web version, as far as I know. Because I need to serve both flask and bokeh. The rest of the site is built in flask.

Comment: I guess let's take a step back. Can you run the example in the repo according to the instructions there? https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/embed/arguments

Comment: @bigreddot I'm having the same issue and I can't run the instructions! get the following error Invalid syntax in "bokeh_server.py" on line 2:
<html lang="en">

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\ziyad\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\application\handlers\code_runner.py", line 76, in __init__
    nodes = ast.parse(source, path)
  File "c:\users\ziyad\anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\Downloads\bokeh_server.py", line 2
    <html lang="en">
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: That is not the same issue. That error is telling you that there is a Python syntax error in your file, `bokeh_server.py`.